# What does '麦上' mean in 小蛮腰 song?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

三百六十五秒 让你受不了 站在**麦上**顶你 继续我的小蛮腰

Do I have to literally translate '麦上' as 'standing on the wheat'?

(I'm very sorry to ask about this song, we're learning about modern Chinese song, thanks in advance)

Comment: not sure what 麦上 means here. Maybe, more context would help.

Answer (score 4):

A couther interpretation of 站在麦上顶你 is 站在麦词的立场上顶持你.

麦 is a short form of 麦词.

麦词 are the words of the rap music.

The MC stands the microphone controller.

[喊麦](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%96%8A%E9%BA%A6) is the corresponding Chinese term in China.
The words are then called 麦词.

顶 means to support, to agree, to say yes, to give a plus (Google+), to give the thumbs up (Facebook) or to give an upvote (here, Stackexchange).
The similar terms are 赞 (Weibo), 推 (Twitter), and so on.

Therefore, 站在麦上顶你 may mean 用麦词支持你.
I support you from the standpoint of the rap words.
I support you with the rap words (so that you can continue ...).

Answer (score 1):

It's a 'I wanna have sex with you' song. Maybe not the best choice for Chinese study!

'麦‘ might be for short'麦克风' . '站在麦上' 'standing at the microphone'

Comment: We're discussing modern culture among the younger generation in China (^_^), which therefore include modern, popular song... I know it's rather vulgar, but we're trying to understand the meaning...